# Compile android application without sending it to emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'd like to know if it's possible (for example by connect the device to the pc) to not send the apk to the emulator.

Thank's

Comment: Please be more specific, you want to debug your app on a device, or you just want to get the apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your device to PC and run the app on the device directly from Eclipse (provided the USB driver for the device is available).

Executing the app (Ctrl+F11) should give you a list of targets to choose from (unless you have set the 'Run configurations' to Automatic and pre-selected an AVD). Choose your phone from the list of 'running Android device'.

Also ensure the 'USB Debugging' is enabled on your device (Settings>Applications>Development).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is easy to do. Just install and use the "Usb Driver Package" that comes with the Android SDK.

To start the application on your device, just check the "Application / USB Debugging" option of your cellphone and start the application on your PC. It works for both running and debugging.